# Merging row based on specific column in Python

Tags: python

I have a csv file like this:

```
year,gender,relation,population
2002,Female,Family/Relative,7
2002,Female,Family/Relative;Other,60
2002,Female,Family/Relative;Unknown,0
2002,Female,Friend,0
2002,Female,Friend;Family/Relative,0
2002,Female,Friend;Family/Relative;Other,0
2002,Female,Friend;Other,0
2002,Female,Friend;Unknown,0
2002,Female,Intimate Partner,0
2002,Female,Intimate Partner;Family/Relative,0
2002,Female,Intimate Partner;Friend,0
2002,Female,Intimate Partner;Friend;Other,0
2002,Female,Intimate Partner;Other,0
2002,Female,Intimate Partner;Unknown,0
2002,Female,Other,10
2002,Female,Other;Unknown,0
2002,Female,Unknown,1116
2002,Male,Family/Relative,0
2002,Male,Family/Relative;Other,0
2002,Male,Family/Relative;Unknown,0
2002,Male,Friend,0
2002,Male,Friend;Family/Relative,0
2002,Male,Friend;Family/Relative;Other,0
2002,Male,Friend;Other,0
2002,Male,Friend;Unknown,0
2002,Male,Intimate Partner,0
2002,Male,Intimate Partner;Family/Relative,0
2002,Male,Intimate Partner;Friend,0
2002,Male,Intimate Partner;Friend;Other,0
2002,Male,Intimate Partner;Other,0
2002,Male,Intimate Partner;Unknown,0
2002,Male,Other,0
2002,Male,Other;Unknown,0
2002,Male,Unknown,0
```

I want to merge row based on the third column, there are 7 categories for the relation column now, However,I want to merge some of them and finally get only six of them. Here is the way I use to merge : The population of "Family/Relative;Other" category will added to the population of "Family/Relative" and "other" categories. The population of "Family/Relative;Unknown" category will add to the population of "Family/Relative" and "Unknown" categories. The Population of "Friend;Family/Relative" category will added to the population of "Friend" and "Family/Relative" category. The population of "Friend;Family/Relative;Other" category will add to the population of "Friend", "Family/Relative" and other categories. The population of "Intimate Partner;Family/Relative" category will added to the population of "Intimate Partner" and "Family/Relative" categories. So far and so on. At the end, there will be just "Family/Relative", "Other", "Unknown", "Intimate Partner", "Friend" these five categories. For example, if the population of "Family/Relative;Unknown" is 10 and population of "Family/Relative" is 5 and "Unknown" is 0. After merging, the population of "Family/Relative" is 15 and "Unknown" is 10.

Below will be a . expected output:

```
year,gender,relation,population
2002,Female,Family/Relative,67
2002,Female,Friend,0
2002,Female,Intimate Partner,0
2002,Female,Other,70
2002,Female,Unknown,1116
2002,Male,Family/Relative,0
2002,Male,Friend,0
2002,Male,Intimate Partner,0
2002,Male,Other,0
2002,Male,Unknown,0
```

Comment: pandas groupby might be what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pandas, etc

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple using the `csv` library and a few lines of Python code. Here's an example:

```py
import csv

def merge_by_relation(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        p = {}
        for i, line in enumerate(reader):
            if i == 0:  # skips column index names
                continue
            population = line[2].split(';')[0] if ';' in line[2] else line[2]
            key = '{},{},{}'.format(line[0], line[1], population)
            if key not in p:
                p[key] = int(line[3])
            else:
                p[key] += int(line[3])
    return p

def write_csv_file(values):
    with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for key, value in values.items():
            csv_line = '{},{}'.format(key, value)
            writer.writerow(csv_line.split(','))

write_csv_file(merge_by_relation('input.csv'))
```

If you want to know more about the CSV library, I'd suggest [my blogpost](https://rooy.works/data/python-csv/). :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I want my output in a CSV format like the expected output I posted.

Comment: @WendyHuang, my bad. I've updated the code. Simply pass the output of `merge_by_relation` into `write_csv_file`.

Comment: I tested your code but nothing come up. The output.csv file did not generate.

Comment: Have you added `write_csv_file(merge_by_relation('input.csv'))` to the file before you ran it?

Comment: where to add it? In the command line? My command to run your script is "Python3 script.py"